Rows with equal height in a multirow tblr table
I have written the following code. It uses the tblr environment from the tabulararray package to typeset a table. The table has an image on the first column and an arbitrary number of rows on the second column. The image on the first column occupies all the rows in that column.
1 paragraph.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c,0.5\textwidth]X[l]},
  column{1} = {leftsep=0pt,rightsep=0pt},
  rowspec = {Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]},
  rowsep = 0pt,
  hlines = 1pt,
  vlines = 1pt,
}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image} & Paragraph no. 1\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

2 paragraphs.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c,0.5\textwidth]X[l]},
  column{1} = {leftsep=0pt, rightsep=0pt},
  rowsep = 0pt,
  rowspec = {Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]},
  hlines = 1pt,
  vlines = 1pt,
}
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image} & Paragraph no. 1 \\
  & Paragraph no. 2 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

3 paragraphs.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c,0.5\textwidth]X[l]},
  column{1} = {leftsep=0pt, rightsep=0pt},
  rowsep = 0pt,
  rowspec = {Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]},
  hlines = 1pt,
  vlines = 1pt,
}
  \SetCell[r=3]{c} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image} & Paragraph no. 1 \\
  & Paragraph no. 2 \\
  & Paragraph no. 3 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

As you can see above, the rows on the second column don't have the same height. I need them to have the same height. So, my question is: How to make the rows in the second column to have the same height?
Note that this problem doesn't occur when the height of all rows together in the second column exceed the height of the image.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c,0.5\textwidth]X[l]},
  column{1} = {leftsep=0pt, rightsep=0pt},
  rowsep = 0pt,
  rowspec = {Q[m]Q[m]Q[m]},
  hlines = 1pt,
  vlines = 1pt,
}
  \SetCell[r=13]{c} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image} & Paragraph no. 1 \\
  & Paragraph no. 2 \\
  & Paragraph no. 3 \\
  & Paragraph no. 4 \\
  & Paragraph no. 5 \\
  & Paragraph no. 6 \\
  & Paragraph no. 7 \\
  & Paragraph no. 8 \\
  & Paragraph no. 9 \\
  & Paragraph no. 10 \\
  & Paragraph no. 11 \\
  & Paragraph no. 12 \\
  & Paragraph no. 13 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


You need to add vspan=even to tblr preamble. For example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c, m, 0.5\textwidth,
               leftsep=0pt, rightsep=0pt] 
             X[l, m]},
  rowsep = 0pt,
  hlines = 1pt,
  vlines = 1pt,
  vspan=even   % <---- added
}
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image} & Paragraph no. 1 \\
  & Paragraph no. 2 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}

Of course it works at any number of rows in the second column. However, you need to define multi row cell with image in the first column accordingly.
